# Does dependency injection by smart pointers violate Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, smart-pointers, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

My concern is that when using either `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` I stick to one ownership model - either injected objects is shared or my own. And I think this is is secondary class responsibility - to care of injected objects lifetime.

So, **does it violates SRP - assuming that class already has some responsibility**.

Some simple example:

```
  class Calculator {
  public:
      Calculator(std::unique_ptr<Adder> adder) : adder(adder) {}
      void add();
  private:
      std::unique_ptr<Adder> adder;
  };
```

When design  changes  - so I will have many different calculators - then I need to change `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr`. So even if `Calculator` main responsibility (to calculate) did not change - I need to change the class.

Wouldn't be better to use simple references for injected objects - and just left the responsibility of injected objects lifetime to some other classes?

Comment: 'change the class' literally yes, but you wouldn't be changing any of the *functionality* of the class so for that reason alone one could argue you're actually not changing the class.

Comment: Contructors aren't considered part of the interface, I'm not sure what the problem with many different calculators with different dependancies is?

Comment: @stijn But I need to change unit tests as well - e.g. injecting AdderMock by either of smart pointers. Anyway - I put this question because I am not sure...

Comment: Note that DI doesn't mean 'inject one single instance everywhere', so another question to ask yourself is whether it's really needed to use a shared Adder instance instead of multiple unique instances? And yes if you make changes to a class you need to change tests. That doesn't mean you are violating SRP though.

Comment: @stijn - this is only example. Assume that `Adder` needs to be shared. The real project is not about `Calculator` nor  `Adder` - it is much more complicated and we have doubts if using smart pointers is not additional "reason to change" when have to frequently change this smart pointer types.

Comment: If you're 'frequently' changing smart pointers you should head back to the design table and rethink the design to start with.. But maybe add a more concrete explanation of what your actual classes do to the question, that makes things more clear for us.

Comment: WRT DI, you should have a conceptual model of which component depends on which other component. No crosslinks are allowed. Any downlink across components must be a shared pointer, any uplink must be a weak pointer to a callback type (and checked on each use).

Comment: @stijn - sure - but I really only want an answer to my simple question...

Comment: @dascandy - is your point that instead of having everywhere references - I should rather have `shared_ptr`? We had so - but that was too big memory overhead in our case.

Comment: The things you share should be substantial enough that the shared_ptr overhead isn't a big deal. If they can reasonably not share the instance, they should by default not be sharing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way we kept member variables in an object is the implementation detail, and it is not related in any way to design principles like [Single Responsibility Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-responsibility-principle)

To illustrate this - you can encapsulate access to your members by some private method - this prevents the changes in class implementation when you changes from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` or vice versa.

```
private:
   Adder& add();
   Adder const& add();
```

Or you can go even further and enclose Adder to some private object - thus preventing it totally from accidental access to "read" adder variable, like:

```
class Calculator 
{
   class AdderProxy
   {
   public:
       using Type = std::unique_ptr<>;
       AdderProxy(AdderType);
       void add(...);    
   };
public:
   Calculator(AdderProxy::Type);

private:
   AdderProxy adder;
```

Or you can just have some DI library, like this [one](https://github.com/boost-ext/di) - and have all kind of injection hidden from application code.